# Cytoscape task is running upon program launch and shrinking window down to unreadable size

Tags: interface, font-size, scaling, cytoscape, shrink

I recently installed cytoscape v3.10.0, when launching the program the window opens normally and then a secondary window labeled cytoscape task opens runs something and the cytoscape interface shrinks down very tiny and you cannot read anything or functionally use the features of the program. I am running this on a windows 10 enterprise 64-bit OS, my display is get at 3840x2160 resolution and at 250% scaling.

I tried scaling the size up even more than 250% then opening it and the same launch process happens and shrinks the interface even smaller so I am not sure what to do here. I am not finding many fixes for this online.

Answer (score 0):

We see this problem every so often on Windows 10 systems, but it doesn't happen on all systems for some reason.  There seems to be a workaround discussed on the net, but it depends on whether you are using the bundled Java or your own installed Java.  In any case, the basic idea is outlined here: https://superuser.com/a/1207925

Comment: Please don't sign posts here. It is "house style" that the profile card is signature enough.